# Can I say $|f(x)g(x)|=||fg||$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Show that $$||fg||\le||f||\space||g||$$
What I have got so far :

$|f(x)| \le\max|f(x)|=$ norm of $f$, $||f||$.$\forall x\in[0,1]$. (Note: I have replaced supremum with maximum.)

$|f(x)||g(x)| =|f(x)g(x)|\le \max |f(x)|g(x)=||f|| \space\space |g|\le \max|f(x)|\space \max|g(x)|=|f||\space\space||g||$

$|f(x)g(x)|\le||f||\space\space||g||$

As I have to show that $||fg||\le||f||\space||g||$
:

Can I say $|f(x) g(x)|=||fg||$? I'm not sure about that  Because $|f(x)g(x)| \le\max|f(x)g(x)|=\max|f(x)| \space \max|g(x)|$

I feel I am missing concept to prove $|f(x) g(x)|=||fg||$, through which I think I finally can prove $||fg||\le||f||\space||g||$

please If you guys could clarify.

Comment: $\max|f(x)g(x)|=\|f\|\|g\|$ is wrong.

Comment: To give an example why it's wrong, let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1 - x$. $\|f\| = \|g\| = 1$, while $\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)g(x)| = \frac 14$.

Comment: Hey @TedShifrin thanks for the response

Comment: Hey @Dmitry thanks for the response. The example makes sense. But how should I use $|f(x)g(x)|\le ||f|| \space ||g||$ to prove $||fg|| \le ||f|| |\space ||g||$.

Comment: @Dmitry. Suppose, let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=3x$ $||f|| = ||g|| =1$.   max$_{x\in [0,1]} \space  |f(x)g(x)|=1$. then the relation holds true.

Comment: hey @MartinR thanks for the response and pointing that out. It provides a helpful hint, But doesn't fully answer the Question. I added my query as an answer in that post. But Still I feel I'm missing a concept to prove the final step. $||fg|| \le ||f|| \space ||g||$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can say max$|f(x) g(x)|=||fg||$. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP you need to be clear on your definitions.

By definition, $$||f|| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|.$$
And similarly, $$||g|| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |g(x)|.$$
And as $fg(x) \doteq f(x)g(x)$, also **by definition**: $$||fg|| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)g(x)|.$$

So with definitions in hand, let us now show the desired result. At each point $x_0 \in [0,1]$:
$$fg(x_0) \doteq f(x_0)g(x_0) \le \max_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)|\max_{x' \in [0,1]} |g(x')| =||f||\cdot ||g||,$$

where the last equation in this above string of relations follows from the def'ns of $||f||, ||g||$. So the above string of relations says in particular:
$$fg(x_0) \le ||f||\cdot ||g||  \ \forall x_0 \in [0,1].$$

And so:

$$\max_{x_0 \in [0,1]} fg(x_0) \le ||f||\cdot ||g||.$$

Thus, the above definition for $||fg||$ implies
$$||fg|| \doteq \max_{x_0 \in [0,1]} fg(x_0) \le ||f||\cdot||g||,$$
which is what you want to prove.

Comment: Hey @Mike, Thanks a lot for the response. I will go through it.

Comment: I just editted @Gaurang Chauhan, my apologies, I wrote this out from my phone!

Comment: You don't need to apologies, I appreciate you responded.

Comment: nice work!, makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: Hey @Mike could you please explain this bit :   max$_{x_0∈[0,1]} fg(x_0)≤||f||⋅||g||.$. like elaborate a bit

Comment: Let $C$ be a positive number and let $h$ be a function $[0,1] \rightarrow R$. If the inequality $h(x_0) \le C$ is satisfied for all $x_0 \in [0,1]$ then so is the inequality $\max_{x_0\in[0,1]} h(x_0) \le C$ satisfied. Thus, setting $h =fg$, if the inequality $fg(x_0) \le C$ is satisfied for all $x_0 \in [0,1]$, then so is the inequality $\max_{x_0 \in [0,1]} fg(x_0) \le C$.

Comment: So here $C=||f|| ×||g||$.

Comment: Thanks mate for the efforts, makes sense @Mike. My bad for the late reply

Comment: Glad I could help Gaurang Chauhan!